# How can use using view controller key Value Observing mechanism

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controller I want to observe data on NextViewController textField any changes in data from ViewController on Button Click Using Key Value Observing Mechanism..

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NextViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()    
{
NextViewController *nextViewConntroller;    
}    
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize txtFieldmarks,txtFieldname,txtFieldroll,nameString;

-(void)save:(id)sender
{
nameString = txtFieldname.text;
   nextViewConntroller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextViewController"];
   // [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"nameString" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
[nextViewConntroller addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"txtname.text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

 [self presentViewController:nextViewConntroller animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

NextViewController.m

```
#import "NextViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation NextViewController
@synthesize txtname,txtmarks,txtroll;

- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


     ViewController *myView = [[ViewController alloc]init];

            [myView  addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"txtFieldname.text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
                   myView.txtFieldname.text = txtname.text;

}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{

        NSLog(@"Keypath");
    NSLog(@"Keypath %@",keyPath);
    NSLog(@"Object %@",object);
    NSLog(@"Change %@",change);
}
```

So I getting a thread NSInternalInconsistencyException

```
2015-07-13 16:29:04.524 KeyValueObserver[3126:113122] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7fb312c2c6a0 of class ViewController was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7fb312c00590> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7fb312c3d4d0: Observer: 0x7fb312c1e2d0, Key path: txtFieldname.text, Options: <New: YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7fb312c400b0>
)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a9ef35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102737bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a9ee6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x0000000102319dd2 NSKVODeallocate + 317
4   KeyValueObserver                    0x0000000102208e2b -[NextViewController Back:] + 427
5   UIKit                               0x0000000102e8c8be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
6   UIKit                               0x0000000102f93410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
7   UIKit                               0x0000000102f927df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
8   UIKit                               0x0000000102ed2308 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
9   UIKit                               0x0000000102ed2c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
10  UIKit                               0x0000000102e9f9b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
11  UIKit                               0x0000000102eaca7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
12  UIKit                               0x0000000102e88103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001029d4551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001029ca41d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001029c9a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001029c9486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
17  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001060809f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
18  UIKit                               0x0000000102e8b420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
19  KeyValueObserver                    0x0000000102209463 main + 115
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010502e145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

So How can I use Key Value Observer In iso Using View Controller..Please Guide me